# Reverse Names Given

Tags: java

I'm looking to reverse the names found in a list given to me (EDIT: given to me from a web scraping of a website) Again not homework

Small sample of list:

```
Baynes, Aron
Bazemore, Kent
Beal, Bradley
Beasley, Malik
Beasley, Michael
Belinelli, Marco
Bell, Jordan
Bembry, DeAndre'
```

I need them as `Aron Bayne`s (or `Aron,Baynes`)

Weirdly people think this is homework problem. THIS IS NOT. I am using NBA player names in a program I have written. I can not post code as the code used is 1000s of lines long. I simply need the ability to reverse the name order in a quick manner compared to my attempts

What I tried: `for loops` using , as a index then working back and forth using substrings. This did not work well for a list of strings as given above

Comment: Hi @Novabomb, you should post the code you've written already, so that we can begin on something concrete

Comment: My code is around 1,500 lines long. I am putting these names into a list which i use to control part of my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all names in file (e.g. `names.txt`):

```
Baynes, Aron
Bazemore, Kent
Beal, Bradley
Beasley, Malik
Beasley, Michael
Belinelli, Marco
Bell, Jordan
Bembry, DeAndre'
```

You can:

- Read line
- split line (using separator)
- display in reverse way

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // File name
        String fileName = "names.txt";
        String separator = ", ";

        String line;

        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] elements = line.split(separator);

                if (elements.length == 2) {
                    System.out.printf("%s %s\n", elements[1], elements[0]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Wrong line: " + line);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Or using `List` instead of files:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                "Baynes, Aron",
                "Bazemore, Kent",
                "Beal, Bradley",
                "Beasley, Malik",
                "Beasley, Michael",
                "Belinelli, Marco",
                "Bell, Jordan",
                "Bembry, DeAndre'"
        ));

        String separator = ", ";

        // Using loop
        for (String person : list) {
            String[] elements = person.split(separator);

            if (elements.length == 2) {
                System.out.printf("%s %s\n", elements[1], elements[0]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong line: " + person);
            }
        }

        // Using stream
        list.forEach(person -> {
            String[] elements = person.split(separator);

            if (elements.length == 2) {
                System.out.printf("%s %s\n", elements[1], elements[0]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong line: " + person);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: They weren't in a .txt however I can put one in a file and do this style

Comment: @Novabomb how you store data?

Comment: In a list in my main driver. This info is gathered thru web scrapping of https://stats.nba.com/players/list/ which i want to put in proper format

Comment: @Novabomb is my solution answering your problem?

Comment: Yes I'll just manually put the output into a file to format then I'll write something to add ""